# LDAP with fallback to FILE-based authentication for svn using apache2

Tags: svn, authentication, ldap, apache2.2, mod-dav-svn

Hy,

I implement a SVN-Server that authenticates users via LDAP protocol against an AD. I use apache2 version 2.2.14 for accessing the repository (HTTP). This works so far.

I want to enhance my config to do simple 'svn-file-based' authentication in case of a user couldn't be authenticated via LDAP (because not defined in the AD). I try this way:

**My Root-Location:**

```
<Location />      
  AuthType basic
  AuthName "<DNS-Name-of-Server>"

  # for LDAP only this is enough (works for me)
  #AuthBasicProvider ldap
  #AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on

  # but I want this...
  # these two lines should make it, as I understand the Apache2 documentation
  AuthBasicProvider ldap file
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off

  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://my.server.com:3268/dc=mydomain,dc=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=serviceusers,OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "secret"

  AuthUserFile /etc/svn/svn-auth # contains svn users, that are not listed in AD
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn/svn-access # handles path-based authorisation

  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

**One of many sub locations (the different repositories):**

```
<Location /repos1>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /opt/svn/repos1

  # again:
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn/svn-auth # contains svn users, that are not listed in AD
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn/svn-access # handles path-based authorisation

  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

That doesn't work. After reloading apache2, I'm still able to authenticate users that are listed in the AD, but the fallback to file-based authentication doesn't work. 
The Apache-Module is enabled (mods-enabled/authn_file.load is present)

Maybe one additional hint:
This configuration also allows a multiple-repository-access approach via HTTP and SVN protocol.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Best regards
ITL

Comment: Am I the only one organizing svn access that way?

Answer (score 0):

My setup is similar to this and it works, maybe you should try moving according to this order, and configure maximum httpd debug log level.

```
<Location /repos1>
  Require valid-user
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /opt/svn/repos1

  # again:
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn/svn-access # handles path-based authorisation
  # Fallback:
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn/svn-auth # contains svn users, that are not listed in AD create using htpasswd

</Location>
```